# What is the chemical equation of the decomposition of natural cork?

Tags: decomposition

I am currently doing a study project on natural cork wine stoppers and I am investigating the emissions of composting natural cork (C123H182O56N). However, I am struggling with setting up the chemical equation of this decomposition. Anyone knows how to tackle this?

Comment: Ultimately, you get carbon dioxide, water and nitrogen or nitrogen oxides. Lots of intermediate steps, of course, and no way to make a sensible list of those. If the decomposition involves fungus, bacteria, etc., then more intermediate steps.

Comment: I believe cork is almost entirely composed of lignin and suberin with some cellulose and hemicellulose thrown in. There should be plenty of info available on the biodegradation of each of those substances separately. It will also depend on how good the aeration of your compost pile is because that will affect the amount of aerobic metabolism vs anaerobic

Comment: What is the origin of the chemical formula of cork you state? Since it is a (varying) blend of natural products (with lignin and cellulose itself describing polymers of varying chemical composition, too), you probably have to rely on empirical data ($\pu{x kg}$ of cork yield $\pu{xk L}$ of $\ce{CO2}$ over time and temperature. Some landfills monitor the release of gases anyway ([example](https://www.epa.gov/lmop/basic-information-about-landfill-gas), [a brief search](https://www.mdpi.com/search?q=landfill+gas)) to draw inspiration.

Comment: Natural cork is not a chemical compound. The meantioned formula is just the supposed empirical element composition recalculated to the empirical formula. Furthermore, the decomposition is biological process of biodegradable material, with part being reused by living organisms.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, natural cork is not just a simple chemical compound. It is a mixture of suberin, lignin, cellulose and other organic compounds and you can't write a simple decomposition reaction. If you want reaction, google "thermal decomposition of 'the individual components e.g. lignin'".

---

The thermochemical decomposition of natural cork has been studied previously:

> The thermochemical degradation of cork from Quercus suber L. was studied in the temperature range 150°C–450°C in relation to mass loss, chemical composition and the influence on the cellular structure. The degradation of cork is strongly dependent on temperature and mass losses become significant at 200°C (15% of initial dry weight) and increase rapidly for higher temperatures (27% at 250 °C, 49% at 300 °C, 62% at 350 °C) until ashing at 450 °C. The polysaccharides are the most heat sensitive components: at 200 °C, hemicelluloses disappear and cellulose is degraded to a considerable extent. Suberin is more resistant and degradation starts at approx. 250 °C; 300 °C-treated samples only contain 7% suberin. The cellular structure of cork is also significantly influenced by temperature. Upon heating, cells expand and the cell walls stretch, attaining at 250 °C a maximum cell volume increase corresponding to a factor of approximately 2. Above 300 °C, the structure of cell walls is considerably changed and show profound physical damage; in the later stages of pyrolysis, a cellular structure is no longer observed.

**Reference:**

1. Pereira, Helena. (**1992**). The thermochemical degradation of cork. Wood Science and Technology. 26. 259-269. [10.1007/BF00200161](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226812544_The_thermochemical_degradation_of_cork)
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/chemhelp/comments/r14w9z/what_is_the_chemical_equation_of_the/